# Vue-router: redirect to route if user does not have permissions

Tags: laravel, vue.js, permissions, vue-router

I have a `vue` project and `laravel` as a `back-end`, i have to check if an user has permissions to access a resource or a view, in the backend i use [laravel permissions](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) to accomplish this, and it work fine, the problem i have now is in the front end.

I fetch the users permissions when it login and save it on the `localStorage`, now how can i prevent a user for enter a certain route if the user does not have the permissions for it?

for example i have these routes

```
    {
      path: 'users',
      name: 'Users',
      component: Users,
      meta : {
        permissions: 'read_users'
      }
    },
    {
      path: 'roles-permissions',
      name: 'RolesPermissions',
      component: RolesPermissions,
      meta : {
        permissions: 'read_roles'
      }
    },
    {
      path: 'roles-permissions/create',
      name: 'CreateRolesPermissions',
      component: CreateRolesPermissions,
      meta : {
        permissions: 'create_roles'
      }
    },
    {
      path: 'roles-permissions/:id/edit',
      name: 'EditRolesPermissions',
      component: EditRolesPermissions,
      meta : {
        permissions: 'edit_roles'
      }
    },
    {
      path: 'customers',
      name: 'Clientes',
      component: CustomersList
    }
```

if the user does not have a permission in `['read_roles','create_roles','edit_roles','read_users']` she should be redirected to `customers`.

var permissions = localStorage.getItem('permissions');
  var can         = to.meta.permissions ? (permissions.includes(to.meta.permissions) || to.meta.permissions == '*') : true;

how can this be done?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a great example of implementing authentication with Vue router: https://scotch.io/tutorials/vue-authentication-and-route-handling-using-vue-router

Basically, you can check permissions before letting the user open the protected component. The easiest way to achieve this is using router guards. In your router definitions:

```
{
  path: '/protected',
  beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
    if (isAuthenticated()) {
      if (!hasPermissionsNeeded(to)) {
        next('/page-to-show-for-no-permission');
      } else {
        next();
      }
    } else {
      next('/page-to-show-for-unauthenticated-users');
    }
  }
}
```

This guard will protect from entering  `/protected` url. Here you can check the working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JwxoMe

Below is an example of aa guard for all routes:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (isAuthenticated()) {
    if (!hasPermissionsNeeded(to)) {
      next('/page-to-show-for-no-permission');
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next('/page-to-show-for-unauthenticated-users');
  }
})
```

More about router guards: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard

Comment: the problem is not the authentication of the user but checking the permissions, if i set the permission needed on the route, how do i get it on the `router.beforeEach`?

Comment: Above code can be used for both: checking authentication and authorization. The same way you can check if the user is logged in and if he has needed permissions.